# YouTube Data API v3 doesn't work when deployed on production server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to create a Stream and live broadcast it. The code works very fine on the localhost but when deployed it's a problem. It doesn't even request for Authorization on the Google account. Looks like it doesn't even interact with it.

> Server Error in '/123456' Application.
>
> Access to the path 'YouTubeDataAPISample.YouTube.Auth.Store' is
>   denied.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the
>   path 'YouTubeDataAPISample.YouTube.Auth.Store' is denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request
>   identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically
>   {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and
>   the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if
>   the application is not impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity will be
>   the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in File
>   Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add"
>   to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account,
>   and check the boxes for the desired access.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   'YouTubeDataAPISample.YouTube.Auth.Store' is denied.]
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   +217    System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost) +11130032
>   System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean
>   checkHost) +136    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path)
>   +33    Google.Apis.Util.Store.FileDataStore..ctor(String folder, Boolean fullPath) +72
>   Template.BusinessLogic.Implementation.YouTubeAPI.AuthenticateOauth(String
>   clientId, String clientSecret, String userName, String apiKey) +220
>   Template.BusinessLogic.Implementation.YouTubeAPI..ctor() +63
>   Template.MVC5.Controllers.VideosController..ctor() +25
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
>   an invocation.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
>   type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +232    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +66    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +55
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type 'Template.MVC5.Controllers.VideosController'. Make
>   sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +77
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +88
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   +191    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +301    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Authorization Code

```
private static YouTubeService AuthenticateOauth(string clientId, string clientSecret, string userName, string apiKey)
        {
            string[] scopes = new string[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube,  // view and manage your YouTube account
                                             YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl,
                                             YouTubeService.Scope.Youtubepartner,
                                             YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubepartnerChannelAudit,
                                             YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly,
                                             YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload};


            // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
            UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                         , scopes
                                                                                         , userName
                                                                                         , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                         , new FileDataStore("YouTubeDataAPISample.YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;

            YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(new YouTubeService.Initializer()
            {
                ApiKey = apiKey,
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "YouTubeDataAPISample"
            });

            return service;           
        }
```

Code for retrieving videos

```
        public PlaylistItemListResponse Videos()
    {
        var playlistItemsListRequest = service.PlaylistItems.List("snippet");

        var channelsListRequest = service.Channels.List("contentDetails");
        channelsListRequest.Mine = true;
        foreach (var find in channelsListRequest.Execute().Items)
        {
            var uploadsListId = find.ContentDetails.RelatedPlaylists.Uploads;

            var nextPageToken = "";
            while (nextPageToken != null)
            {

                playlistItemsListRequest.PlaylistId = uploadsListId;
                playlistItemsListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
                playlistItemsListRequest.PageToken = nextPageToken;

                // Retrieve the list of videos uploaded to the authenticated user's channel.
                var playlistItemsListResponse = playlistItemsListRequest.Execute();

                nextPageToken = playlistItemsListResponse.NextPageToken;
            }
        }
        return playlistItemsListRequest.Execute();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try following the directions on the error page? It tells you exactly what you need to do in order to see the underlying issue.

Comment: Can you show us your code?  There is not really much we can do so solve a problem if we cannot see what you are attempting to do.

Comment: But remember that it's working on the localhost but not when deployed.

Comment: @mason check the question now.

Comment: @MichaelDotKnox check the question now.

Comment: You still did not include the error message details. Follow the directions on the yellow screen - it will show you how to get those error details. Including the code without the actual error details is unlikely to be useful.

Comment: I have voted to reopen now that you have added the relevant error details. The issue appears to be that you're using a file data store with a path that you don't have permissions to. Either get permissions to that folder, change the folder to use something you have permissions to, or use a data store that doesn't require access to the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the error you will have to do one of three things:

1. Log onto the server and hit it on 'localhost' in order to see the detailed error information.
2. Write some custom code to output logs to somewhere so you can read them.
3. Disable `customErrors` as suggested in the error message you have.  **This is a bad idea, but it's your call**.
   It *should* set to `remoteonly`.

Comment: We have tried all of your solutions. For 1. It works on localhost but not on a  deployed solution. For 2. It doesn't execute the try and catch blocks. For 3. It says the OBJECT OF A REFERENCE IS NOT SET TO AN INSTANCE OF AN OBJECT.

Comment: So add logging outside of those try/catch blocks. It sounds like it's throwing errors outside of that then, right?

Comment: @XolaniChristopher You're writing `InnerExeption` which is no use and probability `null` anyway.  You want `ex.Message`.

Comment: @KSib the problem is YouTubeDataAPISample.YouTube.Auth.Store in my Authorization Code. What should I put there?

Comment: It works now. Thanks to all of you for your time. The problem was, FileDataStore("YouTubeDataAPISample.YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result; I changed it to new FileDataStore(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "App_Data"), true)).Result;

Comment: Which creates a correct path for me to store a DataStoreFile.